# Add a sort command button in excel 2016

Tags: excel, sorting, button, vba

I am able to use the sort function on the Data panel. Is there a way to add a command button and link that with the function so instead of going to the sort function, just click the button to sort a column? Or is the case of using a macro?

Comment: You won't be able to link the button to the sort function without some VBA code.  It's relatively easy to use the Macro Recorder to generate that code so give it a try and then, if you have problems, update your question to show what you tried and tell us how it didn't work, and we will be happy to assist you.  (You could also add the sort function to the Quick Access toolbar, if all you are trying to do is get at it quickly.)

Comment: (If you do want to add it to the Quick Access toolbar, just right-click it on the Data panel, and select "Add to Quick Access toolbar".)

Comment: YowE3k, thanks. Just one thing. The sorting by list is not showing correctly. The order is A, B, C, D in the list but it is being sorted B, C, D, A. Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't explain why it isn't being sorted in the correct order without seeing the data - and if the issue is solely with the way Excel's built-in search is working, the question will be off-topic on SO.  SO is for programming-related questions.  (The question **might** be on-topic on SuperUser - but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Closing it now.